# How do I get visual studio code to recognize docker's python interpreter?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, fastapi

I am doing a course in which I make an application using fastapi. I started creating a virtual environment with fastapi and uvicorn, later what I did was continue the development using docker containers, one for the application and another for the database. There is a file called requirements.txt, and when the python image (based on python:3.10-slim-buster) is built all the dependencies are installed. However, in my visual studio code it does not recognize these dependencies since it selects my local version of python as interpreter. I don't know how this works, but is there any way that visual studio code uses the version of python that I have in the container with its dependencies as interpreter?

Comment: use VSC Remote to get into the container

Answer (score 1):

Inside VS Code, go into your python file, do `ctrl + shift + p` (Windows)/`shift + command + p` (Mac) to `Python: select interpreter`.

`Enter interpreter path`, go to the path of the virtual environment with your dependencies you created at the beginning and select the python executable.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if all of your dependencies are installed inside the docker container instead of a local venv, you can do the following:

1. Make sure your container is running
2. Install the [Dev Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) VSCode Extension
3. In VSCode, go to Command Palette (`F1`) -> `Dev Containers: Attach to Running Container...` > `[docker container]`
4. In the new VSCode window, open the directory in which your code lives in the docker, e.g., `/opt/app`
5. Install the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) VSCode Extension
6. In the docker shell, run `which python` to see where docker's python lives
7. Command Palette (`F1`) -> `Python: Select Interpreter` -> paste the path from Step 6

Tah dah!

Comment: Nice sharing!!!